# how to resolve error: TypeError: app.listen is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node.js and I was working on my first project. I was getting error TypeError: app.listen is not a function while starting the app.
    Could you please help how to solve this issue?

Here's my `app.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const routes  = require("./routes/index");

const app = express();
app.use('/',routes);

module.exports = app;
```

`routes/index.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/',(req,res) => res.send("It works!!"));
module.exports = router;
```

`start.js`:

```
const app = require("./app");
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {

    console.log('Express is running on port ${server.address().port}');
});
```

Comment: does `app.listen` work in `app.js`?

Comment: I reproduced your problem and it works fine ,make sure you have express installed in your system npm install express

Comment: How are you starting your app?

Comment: Hi, I have installed nodemon and in package.json, I have changed scripts section like:"scripts": { "watch": "nodemon ./start.js"} and I am running command 
"npm run watch" just to see if it works.

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score -2):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(Port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${Port}`);
})
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.